# convert txt to columnated file

Tags: bash, awk

I need to convert test.txt file to a columnated file.

I know how to convert it with awk if the number of lines after each keyword are same but they are different in this example.

```
awk 'NR % 5 {printf "%s ", $0; next}1' test.txt
```

if the number of lines are same here is the code but this one will not work with this input file.

Anyway to convert this? Please advise.

**test.txt**

```
"abc"
4
21
22
25
"standard"
1
"test"
4
5
10
11
12
```

**Expected Output:**

```
"abc" 4 21 22 25
"standard" 1 
"test" 4 5 10 11 12
```

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\""}{$1=$1}1' test.txt`

Comment: See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: or `awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\""} $1=$1'  test.txt`

Comment: @Cyrus and @oguzismail: `awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\""} $1=$1'` or `awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\""}{$1=$1}1'` both produce a trailing line with `"` on it because of the final field...

Comment: @dawg: Good catch!

Comment: @oguzismail: [See for yourself](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BXSkxKVmJy4TLyJDLyIjLyJRLqbgkMS8lsShFicuQS6kktbgEJG3KZWjAZWjIZWikrlCjkJ5Ynq2g7uTq7ulXHRRs6w/ESjF5MUpKtdUqhrYqhrWG6v//AwA)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (/^"/ ? ors : OFS), $0; ors=ORS} END{print ""}' file
"abc" 4 21 22 25
"standard" 1
"test" 4 5 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit magic, but works in this case:

```
sed -z 's/\n"/\n\x01"/g' |
tr '\n' ' ' |
tr $'\x01' '\n'
```

1. Each "header" starts is a string between `" ... "`. So:
2. Using `sed` I put some delimter (I chose 0x01 in hex) between a newline and a `"`, everywhere in the file. Note that `-z` is a gnu extension.
3. Then I substitute all newlines for a space.
4. Then I substitute all `0x01` bytes for newlines.

This method is a little tricky, but is simply and works in cases where the header starts with some certain character on the beginning of the line.

Live version available at [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/GdxI3K).

One can get with `sed` without gnu extension by using for example:

```
sed '2,$s/^"/\x01"/'
```

ie. for lines greater then the second if the line starts with a `"`, then add the `0x01` byte on the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '/^"/{if (s) print s; s=$0; next} {s=s OFS $0} END{print s}' file
"abc" 4 21 22 25 
"standard" 1 
"test" 4 5 10 11 12
```

Or with `perl`:

```
$ perl -0777 -lnE 'for (/^"[^"]+"\R(?:[\s\S]+?)(?=^"|\z)/mg) {tr /\n/ /; say} ' file
```

If your fields do not have spaces in them, you can use a simple `tr` and `sed` pipe:

```
$ cat file | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -E 's/ ("[^"]*")/\
\1/g'
```

Or GNU sed:

```
$ cat file | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -E 's/ ("[^"]*")/\n\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

with GNU `awk`

```
$ awk -v RS='\n"' '{$1=$1; printf "%s", rt $0; rt=RT}' file
"abc" 4 21 22 25
"standard" 1
"test" 4 5 10 11 12
```

Comment: That won't print a newline at the end of the last line of output so it's output won't be a POSIX text file.

Answer (score 0):

While an `awk` or `sed` solution is advisable, since the question is also tagged `bash`, you can do all that is needed with a simple read loop and a flag variable to control the newline output for the first iteration. Essentially, you are reading each line and using the string indexing *parameter expansion* to test whether the first character is a non-digit, and on the 1st iteration simply output the string, for all additional iterations, output the string preceded by a `'\n'`. If the line begins with a digit, simply output it with a space preceding.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i n=0          ## simple flag to omit '\n' on first string output

while read -r line; do  ## read each line
    [[ ${line:0:1} =~ [^0-9] ]] && {    ## begins with non-digit
        ## 1st iteration, just output $line, rest output '\n$line'
        ((n == 0)) && printf "%s" "$line" || printf "\n%s" "$line"
    } || printf " %s" "$line"   ## begins with digit - output " $line"
    n=1     ## set flag
done < "$1"
echo ""     ## tidy up with newline
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash fmtlines test.txt
"abc" 4 21 22 25
"standard" 1
"test" 4 5 10 11 12
```

While `awk` and `sed` will generally be faster (as a general rule), here with nothing more than a `while read` loop and a few conditionals and parameter expansions, the native bash solution would not be bad by comparison.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: To be clear though, as well as being significantly longer to write that solution can modify the input lines (e.g. it will at least remove any leading or training blanks from the input) and will be orders of magnitude slower to execute than an awk solution so there's no reason to ever use it. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219

Comment: Yep, agree with all the information. That's why I tried to emphasize that the `awk` or `sed` solutions were advisable. But for a person who does not yet know the `sed` or `awk` syntax (which he/she should learn) and only has a 20 line file to deal with, the performance penalties are not significant. `IFS` can be unset or tweaked to control whitespace and splitting.

Comment: IMHO in that situation the user should just learn how to do it in awk instead of learning how to do it in bash since there's no benefit to doing it in bash.

Comment: I agree that `awk` is the tool for the job, but that `awk` is the only tool that will do, is some what a slippery slope. I guess it is the same as why would anyone learn Java or Ruby or Python where performance will always be inferior to an implementation in C. That doesn't make a Java or Ruby or Python implementation wrong, just non-optimal. The same applies here. The bash implementation is not wrong, it's just non-optimal in the same sense.

Comment: I'm not saying awk is the only tool you could use (though it is the only applicable tool that comes as standard on all UNIX boxes), I'm just saying you should not use a shell loop for it. If someone is faced with this problem and they don't know awk then this would be a perfect opportunity to learn it since it's exactly the kind of problem that the guys who invented shell invented awk for shell to call to solve.

Comment: Could not agree more.